# How to set dns server in node.js resolve query?

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm trying to set Google DNS server `8.8.8.8` in Node.js resolve query.

What is the correct way to do so? In command line usually we can do the following:

```
$ nslookup stackoverflow.com 8.8.8.8

Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Address: 151.101.65.69
Address: 151.101.129.69
Address: 151.101.193.69
```

But its not quite clear how to make same approach in Node.js

```
require('dns').resolve('stackoverflow.com', function (err, addresses) {
  console.log(err, addresses);
});

// => null [ '151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69', '151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69' ]
```

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From nodejs doc: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_setservers_servers

```
dns.setServers([
   '4.4.4.4',
   '[2001:4860:4860::8888]',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command:

```
npm config set dns 8.8.8.8
```