# why node js is slower than chrome?

Tags: node.js, npm-request

I am creating a website using `nodejs`. In a page of my website, i request to google then parse its results and send them to the user. I use [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module of `npm` to request to google. `request` module has a flag called `time` that if i set it to true then `request` gives me details of timing of the request. I request to google like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    return request({
        url: 'https://<google-ip>/search?q=' + req.query.query + '&num=30&start=0',
        headers: {
            'host': 'www.google.com'
        },
        strictSSL: false,
        time: true,
        gzip: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        res.send(
            {
                'starts_at: ':{
                'timings.socket':response.timings.socket,
                'timings.lookup':response.timings.lookup,
                'timings.connect': response.timings.connect,
                'timings.response': response.timings.response,
                'timings.end': response.timings.end
            },
            'duration: ':{
                'timingPhases.wait': response.timingPhases.wait,
                'timingPhases.dns': response.timingPhases.dns,
                'timingPhases.tcp': response.timingPhases.tcp,
                'timingPhases.firstByte': response.timingPhases.firstByte,
                'timingPhases.download': response.timingPhases.download,
                'timingPhases.total': response.timingPhases.total
            }
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the output is here:

```
{
    starts_at:
        {
            timings.socket: 3.725953000015579,
            timings.lookup: 3.725953000015579,
            timings.connect: 117.76885500003118,
            timings.response: 692.0431389999576,
            timings.end: 1220.5685750000412
        },
    duration:
        {
            timingPhases.wait: 3.725953000015579,
            timingPhases.dns: 0,
            timingPhases.tcp: 114.0429020000156,
            timingPhases.firstByte: 574.2742839999264,
            timingPhases.download: 528.5254360000836,
            timingPhases.total: 1220.5685750000412
        }
}
```

But when i search the same query in chrome i get these results:

[image]

I do not know why these numbers are very different. `tcp` time in `nodejs` takes about 114 miliseconds but in chrome it takes about 0 milisecond. Also both chrome and `nodejs` server are in a same region but `time-to-first-byte` in `nodejs` is slower than chrome about 245 miliseconds.

How can i improve `nodejs` to be like chrome?

Comment: Could be kind of a "cahed" ip from chrome???

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Thanks for fast reply. I am using ip address of google so it can not be.

Comment: I would create an automatic "ready to search" ip connection under my own browser if I were google. Don't you?? Did you compared the results to another browser different than google's chrome?

Comment: I mean, maybe google gives quicker respones because of it's chrome, or chrome has an internal google's functionality that allows to connect faster..

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I have tested google in `firefox` and i got the same results. I mean google is so faster than my `nodejs` server.

Comment: which dns servers are u using with your node.js servers? are the same as your OS's ones?

Comment: my device and the `nodejs` server are in a same city so i think both of them uses same `dns` server. I have tested this in `localhost` and got the same result. I mean i do not think main reason is `dns`.

Comment: The DNS is something configured in your local system, and it can change.lt's not related to your geographical position. Please, check this answer and configure the 8.8.8.8 DNS that appears there https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453257/3617531

Comment: Check also this one @hamid -> https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns here appears how to get the ip, and then call it

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985367/node-js-dns-resolve-vs-dns-lookup

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz If i use `ping` command to find the ip address does it give right ip address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200440/discussion-between-alejandro-teixeira-munoz-and-hamid).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delays in HTTP requests via Node.js compared to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894611/delays-in-http-requests-via-node-js-compared-to-browser)